# How to detect when terminal is in focus using CPython 3.9?

Tags: python, terminal, onfocus

How is it possible to detect when a terminal (CPython 3.9) is in focus ?
Cant find any solution for that.

In a Python script, I have a global keyboard hook that takes every keyboard-input, where I need it to ignore input when terminal is off focus.

I'm using this package: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard,  that works fine cross-platform (Win32 and Linux) except that it also receives when in off-focus.